# Global cache config of debootstrap

Tags: debian

How should one configure the cache of `debootstrap` globally? I haven't found its configuration file, I have to specify the local mirror all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`debootstrap` does not have a config file. You can set the environment variable `http_proxy` for debootstrap to use a http proxy server for caching.

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.host:port/ debootstrap …
```

You can also use something like `approx` to set-up an caching server for debian packages.

If you want to use debootstrap with a config file have a look at [grml-debootstrap](http://grml.org/grml-debootstrap/) it is part of debian nowadays. It allows you (besides some other features) to have a global configuration file for all your `grml-debootstrap` calls.